# jQuery Masonry Layout - How to align images

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have built a jQuery masonry layout that pulls recent posts from different categories and displays them on the homepage.

I am not sure how to amend the code in order to achieve two things:

1. Remove the small white gap underneath some of the images so that they are flush with each other.
2. Align the bottom row of images so that they do not overhang. I would like them to form a neat straight line in the same way that they do on the top row. I'm not sure if this is possible other than only displaying images of certain dimensions.

This is the current layout: [test-page](http://104.244.127.200/~qmintest/test-homepage/)

I would like the bottom row to always align in the same way as the image below: [image: example layout]

HTML/jQuery:

```
<div id="container">
<?php
$recent_posts_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 
'posts_per_page' => 8, 'category_name' => 'technology', 
'Fashion/Beauty', 'Art', 'Watches/Jewellery', 'Travel',));
 while ($recent_posts_query->have_posts()){
 $recent_posts_query->the_post(); ?>
 <div class="masonryImage"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></div>
 <?php } ?>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(window).load(function() {
  var container = document.querySelector('#container');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.masonryImage',
    columnWidth: '.masonryImage',                
  });  

    });


</script>
```

CSS:

```
`/* Makes two columns */
 .masonryImage {
 width: 50%;
 }

 /* Makes three columns */
 .masonryImage {
 width: 33%;
 }

 /* Makes four columns */
 .masonryImage {
 width: 25%;
 } `
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
.masonryImage img(vertical-align: middle;)
```